# i want to display the list of pruducts based on the choice of the category chosing -django

Tags: python, django

so i want to khow what i have to add in the urls.py and in the views.py to add this functionnality: if i click in one of this categories  [here my categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwEXw.png) display some products based on the category chosen.

and this the  models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to ='images/',default="images/default.jpg")
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return '/static/images/default.png'
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
    help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is the template :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <form method="get" action="">
              {% for c in active_categories %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href='#'>{{ c.name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else</a>
      </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplest way. You can change code as per requirement.

**urls.py**

```
from . import views # import views.py file 

urlpatterns = [
    path('product_list/<id>', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def product_list(request, id):
   products = Product.objects.filter(categories__pk=id)
   context = {
      'products': products,
   }
   return render(request, 'product_list.html', context)
```

**link template** (Check the change in link)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <form method="get" action="">
              {% for c in active_categories %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'product_list' id=c.pk %}">{{ c.name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else</a>
      </form>
</div>
```

**product_list.html**

```
Your regular html things + 
{% for product in products %}
<p>{{ product.name }}</p>
<p>{{ product.price }}</p>
{% empty %} # in case there is no product in this category
<p>No product available for this category</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will help. Please comment if get any error.

If you products to load without refreshing the page, you can use ajax. Reply if need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')
    context = {}

    if category_id:
        products = Product.objects.filter(categories__id=category__id)
        context["products"] = products

    return render(request, 'template', context)
```

template

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <form method="get" action="">
              {% for c in active_categories %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href='?category_id={{ c.id }}'>{{ c.name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else</a>
      </form>
</div>
```